# Can I travel back into the US with a foreign passport and a Certificate of Naturalization?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, us-citizens, dual-nationality

I need to travel internationally on the day of my citizenship interview. Luckily the interview is really early in the morning and my flight is in the early evening.

There is a slight chance they ask me to take the oath on the same day. If this is the case, they will take away my Green Card. I have been advised not to reschedule this as the process may sometimes take more than 6 months.

My question is: Can I travel back to the United States with a foreign passport AND my Certificate of Naturalization?
Will American Airlines let me board the plane? Will the Customs Officer let me back into the US?

I will be gone for 9 days so I have also looked at the possibility of having a expedited passport sent to France. But there are so many things that could go wrong in this scenario.

I am starting to think that my best option would be to decline a same-day oath ceremony. This way I can keep my Green Card until I get back into the US.

One of my major concerns with getting an emergency passport expedited to France is that I need to send my Certificate of Naturalization along with the passport application. So if this does not go through fast enough, I would have zero proof of citizenship.

Comment: Is your other passport one that would grant you entry to the US without a visa?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: You could also look into the possibility of [getting an emergency passport in Paris, Marseille, or Strasbourg](https://fr.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/passports/).  You should also consider whether you can enter the Schengen area without a US passport after you naturalize.  Many countries provide that their citizens lose citizenship when they naturalize elsewhere.  If yours does so, it would be fraudulent to use its passport after naturalizing in the US.

Comment: I have thought about getting a US passport in Paris actually. I sent an email for some questions but never got a clear answer back. But you make a good point. I will take a look at that as a last resort before declining same day oath. Thanks so much

Comment: The oath ceremonies are _months_ after the interview. The decision is not made at the interview, the interviewing officer just _recommends_ approval. I wouldn't worry about not having the green card.

Answer (score 3):

No airline will board you on a direct flight to the US without a passport or green card. This is because check-in staff rely on the TIMATIC database to verify documentation, which says a passport, green card, emergency passport, transportation letter or (if flying from Canada) NEXUS card is required to enter the US by air.

(in addition, you cannot get a visa as a US citizen, and you state that your foreign passport would require one)

**However**, per TIMATIC, US citizens can fly to and enter Canada with only their naturalization certificate. From there you can cross into the US by land and, if need be, catch a domestic flight.

So either get that emergency passport, **or** book your return trip through Canada. In the latter case, if you face problems at check-in/boarding for the flight to Canada, insist that the staff check TIMATIC, putting USA as your nationality.

Comment: But the OP *does* have a passport. It's just not a US passport.

Comment: @brhans It will require either an ESTA or visa, unless it's Canadian. ESTAs are often rejected for dual citizens

Comment: Would it help the OP, if travelling via Canada, to transit at a pre-clearance airport to avoid having to cross over by land?

Comment: ...without a passport *or green card,* no?  I mean, maybe the six month wait for naturalization isn't so bad compared to the hassle of getting an expedited passport during the trip.

Comment: @brhans Unsure of that TBH, but as airline policy remains largely the same and you see those CBP officers *before* the flight, my qualified guess is no.